# input realtime data from google sheets into urlfetch google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, get, put, google-sheets-api, ethereum

I'm trying to input user fed data from google sheet to modify the API link in real time. I tried using the getActivecell Sheet, but I believe I would have to use put instead of get? Or is there a simpler way to do so? TIA!

```
function TransactionVerification() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var response=UrlFetchApp
    .fetch("https://api.ethplorer.io/getTxInfo/(sheet.getActiveCell(2,2))?apiKey=freekey");
   var json = response.getContentText();
   var data = JSON.parse(json)
   sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue([data.success]);
   sheet.getRange(2,5).setValue([data.from]);
   sheet.getRange(2,6).setValue([data.to]);
   sheet.getRange(2,4).setValue([data.value]);
   sheet.getRange(2,7).setValue([data.gasUsed]);
   Logger.log(data);
```

Comment: Show your log print out from your `Logger.log(data);`  If there is an error, then open the "view" menu, and choose "Execution Transcript."  That will show what line of code failed.  Your question may be partly about how to use the [Ethplorer API](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API?from=etop)  I don't see anything about needing to use a POST request in that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title I hope to understand your question correctly.
You're currently not inserting the value of the active cell in your url.
Try the code below. This code takes the value of the active cell and puts it in the url.

```
function TransactionVerification() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var url = "https://api.ethplorer.io/getTxInfo/" + sheet.getActiveCell().getValue() + "?apiKey=freekey"
   var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   var json = response.getContentText();
   var data = JSON.parse(json)
   sheet.getRange(2,3).setValue([data.success]);
   sheet.getRange(2,5).setValue([data.from]);
   sheet.getRange(2,6).setValue([data.to]);
   sheet.getRange(2,4).setValue([data.value]);
   sheet.getRange(2,7).setValue([data.gasUsed]);
   Logger.log(data);
```

From the url in your initial code it almost looks like you want to take the value of the cell in row 2 column 2. If that's the case, change the `url` var to:

```
var url = "https://api.ethplorer.io/getTxInfo/" + sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue() + ?apiKey=freekey"
```